# How to make a sqlplus quit when database is not available?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

i have a problem with sqlplus on windows batch.
I have SQLPLUS 10.2

i'm trying to connect to a database through a windows script.cmd

script.cmd only launches : `sqlplus test/Test@mydatabase @script.sql`

The problem is when the database is not available, the sqlplus says

```
ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
Enter user-name :
```

and waits for input ..  and blocks the .cmd

How can i adapt the script to stop immediately when the database is not avaliable or just to avoid waiting for user prompts ?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do `sqlplus -l test/Test@mydatabase @script.sql`; the `-l` flag means it will only try to connect once, and if it fails for any reason will exit instead of prompting. Look at the output of `sqlplus -?`, or see [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch3.htm#i1169506).

Answer (score 0):

may be you should think about using [TNSPING utility](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsping). You can use it within CMD script before trying to connect to db with sqlplus. In this case you should analyse its output.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with 2 connects.

First one will spool result to a file.

In the second one check what is in that file. If you don't encounter ORA-12541 or any other error messages then call the second script.

You can make all these commands inside one batch script and call it with

```
SQLPLUS @script.sql
```

and inside use

```
connect test/Test@mydatabase
```